# How to append a "non-free" component to /etc/apt/sources.list. Steam install

Tags: linux, debian

I have bought a chromebook and it has come with the os Debian Linux system of which I have no idea how to use or work. I am trying to install Steam on my computer and am following this tutorial: https://wiki.debian.org/Steam#A64-bit_systems_.28amd64.29

I have fallen upon the first step as I am trying to create a new list or even append this non-free component to the current `sources.list`. However I am confused as to how to append it as running the command `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free` I am told `deb` is not a command. This would be fine if I then knew how to create a list and add it.

Would someone be able to help me as to how to add this non-free component to the source.list file. My understanding is very basic.

Thanks

Comment: `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free` is the line of text that needs to be added to sources.list file. There are some tips on how to do that in this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/197603

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

or:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

as follows:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

<kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd> , <kbd>Enter</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd> to save

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
```